# How to put labels at the bottom of the chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

I'm developing a logarithmic graph as shown below:

[image]

The labels of each point are located right next to the point, and this is what I do not want, because what I am looking for is that the labels are located at the bottom of the graph, just in the direction on the x axis that corresponds to it.

Its encoding with hard code is as follows:

```
Series series = Chart1.Series["Series1"];
Series seriesPuntos = new Series();
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(76.20, 100.0);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(63.50, 100.0);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(50.80, 100.0);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(38.10, 100.0);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(25.40, 98.6);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(19.05, 90.0);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(12.70, 83.0);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(9.53, 75.9);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(4.75, 59.8);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(2.36, 46.8);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(1.18, 39.3);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.85, 36.8);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.60, 30.7);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.42, 27.1);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.30, 25.7);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.25, 24.0);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.18, 21.9);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.15, 20.6);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.10, 19.7);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.074, 18.3);
Chart1.Series.Add(seriesPuntos);

Chart1.Series[1].XValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
Chart1.Series[1].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;

Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
Chart1.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;

Chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.DarkRed;
Chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 1;
Chart1.Series[0].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;

Chart1.Series[1].Color = Color.DarkRed;
Chart1.Series[1].BorderWidth = 15;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].BorderWidth = 1;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 2;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 100;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;

series.Points.AddXY(76.20, 100.0);
series.Points.AddXY(63.50, 100.0);
series.Points.AddXY(50.80, 100.0);
series.Points.AddXY(38.10, 100.0);
series.Points.AddXY(25.40, 98.6);
series.Points.AddXY(19.05, 90.0);
series.Points.AddXY(12.70, 83.0);
series.Points.AddXY(9.53, 75.9);
series.Points.AddXY(4.75, 59.8);
series.Points.AddXY(2.36, 46.8);
series.Points.AddXY(1.18, 39.3);
series.Points.AddXY(0.85, 36.8);
series.Points.AddXY(0.60, 30.7);
series.Points.AddXY(0.42, 27.1);
series.Points.AddXY(0.30, 25.7);
series.Points.AddXY(0.25, 24.0);
series.Points.AddXY(0.18, 21.9);
series.Points.AddXY(0.15, 20.6);
series.Points.AddXY(0.10, 19.7);
series.Points.AddXY(0.074, 18.3);

Chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
Chart1.Series[0].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.LabelsAngleStep90;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "% QUE PASA EN PESO";
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleFont = new Font("Roboto", 11, FontStyle.Bold);

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "ABERTURA (mm)";
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleFont = new Font("Roboto", 11, FontStyle.Bold);


Chart1.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
Chart1.Series[0].LabelBackColor = Color.White;
Chart1.Series[0].LabelAngle = 90;

Chart1.Series[0].IsXValueIndexed = true;
Chart1.Series[1].IsXValueIndexed = true;
```

View:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" BorderlineWidth="14" Width="990px" Height="450" class="card-img-top" Style="width: auto; !important">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Line"></asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
            <Titles>
                <asp:Title Font="Roboto, 12pt, style=Bold" Name="Title1" Text="CURVA GRANULOMÉTRICA">
                    <Position Height="3.862135" Width="92" X="8" Y="1" />
                </asp:Title>
            </Titles>
        </asp:Chart>
```

What I'm looking for is that the labels of each point are located at the bottom of the graph as shown below:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your example don't seem to work, at least in my machine (and I found some indications online as well). You can't use AxisX.IsLogarithmic with Series.IsXValueIndexed.
- I don't know why your code has two series with the same values.
  If you want to use a line and highlight the points you should use the MarkerXXX properties:

```
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series.MarkerColor = Color.Red;
series.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
series.MarkerSize = 4;
```

- I don't think there is any way of doing what you want "off the shelf".
  You have to use AxisX.CustomLabels. Something like:

```
var series = Chart1.Series["Series1"];
series.Points.AddXY(76.20, 100.0);
series.Points.AddXY(63.50, 100.0);
series.Points.AddXY(50.80, 100.0);
series.Points.AddXY(38.10, 100.0);
series.Points.AddXY(25.40, 98.6);
series.Points.AddXY(19.05, 90.0);
series.Points.AddXY(12.70, 83.0);
series.Points.AddXY(9.53, 75.9);
series.Points.AddXY(4.75, 59.8);
series.Points.AddXY(2.36, 46.8);
series.Points.AddXY(1.18, 39.3);
series.Points.AddXY(0.85, 36.8);
series.Points.AddXY(0.60, 30.7);
series.Points.AddXY(0.42, 27.1);
series.Points.AddXY(0.30, 25.7);
series.Points.AddXY(0.25, 24.0);
series.Points.AddXY(0.18, 21.9);
series.Points.AddXY(0.15, 20.6);
series.Points.AddXY(0.10, 19.7);
series.Points.AddXY(0.074, 18.3);

series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
series.YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series.Color = Color.DarkRed;
series.BorderWidth = 1;
series.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
series.MarkerColor = Color.Red;
series.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
series.MarkerSize = 4;

var chartArea = Chart1.ChartAreas[0];
chartArea.BorderWidth = 1;
chartArea.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;

chartArea.AxisY.Interval = 2;
chartArea.AxisY.Minimum = 0;
chartArea.AxisY.Maximum = 100;
chartArea.AxisY.Title = "% QUE PASA EN PESO";
chartArea.AxisY.TitleFont = new Font("Roboto", 11, FontStyle.Bold);

chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90;
chartArea.AxisX.Title = "ABERTURA (mm)";
chartArea.AxisX.TitleFont = new Font("Roboto", 11, FontStyle.Bold);

chartArea.AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;
chartArea.AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;
chartArea.AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;

//Axis is in log, so the CustomLabels fromPosition and toPosition should be as well - This gave me a small headache
var logBase = Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LogarithmBase;
//Define the interval to show the text
var customLabelInterval = Math.Log(0.01, logBase);
foreach (var seriesPoint in series.Points)
{
    chartArea.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(Math.Log(seriesPoint.XValue, logBase) - customLabelInterval, Math.Log(seriesPoint.XValue, logBase) + customLabelInterval, seriesPoint.XValue.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
}
```

Resulting in

[image: Result chart of the code above]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the lines in logarithmic scales are great, I didn't know it could be done that way, I used **Chart1.ChartAreas [0] .AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true; Chart1.ChartAreas [0] .AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;** on the other hand you are right I made two lists unnecessarily, one for the lines and one for the points. I also had the idea to put two lists with the Y axis at zero but I did not know how to put the labels, so your answer is just what I was looking for.